# copying array from button1 to button2

Tags: c#

i'm beginner at c# and programming in total..
so i'm working on this code in school right now, where i have to generate 21 random numbers between 1-21 (you can have duplicates of numbers).
i have made the code and it's working sorta... it generates the numbers in listbox1 but it's not the same numbers i get  sorted in listbox3.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] a = new int[21];
            Random tal = new Random();


            for (int x = 1; x < a.Length; x++)
            {
                a[x] = tal.Next(1, 21);
            }
            for (int x = 1; x < a.Length; x++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(a[x]);
            }
            foreach (int i in a)
            {
                Array.Sort(a);
                listBox3.Items.Add(a[i]);
            }
            int min = a[1];
            for (int x = 1; x < a.Length; x++)
                if (a[x] < min)
                    min = a[x];
            listBox2.Items.Add(min);
            int max = a[20];
            for (int x = 1; x > a.Length; x++)
                if (a[x] < max)
                    max = a[x];
            listBox2.Items.Add(max);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int[] a = new int[21];
            Random tal = new Random();
            a.Clone();

            foreach (int i in a)
            {
                Array.Sort(a);
                listBox3.Items.Add(a[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Break the problem down into much smaller parts and work on each piece separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Array begin with index 0, so change all your loops to start from 0:

```
 for (int x = 0; x < a.Length; x++)
```

instead of

```
for (int x = 1; x < a.Length; x++)
```

and also `int min = a[0];` not `int min = a[1];`

2.Sort the array outside the for loop, there is no need to do it over and over:

```
Array.Sort(a);
foreach (int i in a)
{
    listBox3.Items.Add(a[i]);
}
```

the items must be the same (but different order).

and also you are cloning a (`a.Clone();`) and actually not assigning it to anything, so its an extra code.

Comment: the (a.clone();) wasn't finished, cause i was trying to search online for it, but if i want the button_click3 to be used for sorting the numbers generate by clicking button_click1, should i copy the array ? and if so, how do i do that? because when i use array.copy(a); it gives me error in button_click3

Comment: well the array `a` is defined in `button1_click()` scope and invalid outside it. you can either declare `a` in a bigger scope (inside your form calss) just after your form class begins, or use the listbox1 items (int button3) for sorting: `int a = listbox1.Items.Select(x=> int.Parse(x));` and then use the new `a` array.

Comment: thx alot! so that means if i move the int[] a= new int[21]; up to form class, i can use it again down at button3_click right?

Comment: the code in my comment was wrong it should be: `int[] a = listbox1.Items.Select(x=> int.Parse(x)).ToArray();`

Comment: Hello again @Ashkan so i now got the whole thing to work with the same numbers and new button ect. the only problem i have is that i can only get sorting to work descending, when i have to make it ascending. a.orderbydescinding(x=>x=).ToArray(); is working, but what should i use for ascending order?

Comment: @Tim instead of `OrderByDescending` try `OrderBy`

Answer (score 0):

Variables have *scope*.

What this means for you right now, is that the `a` in `button1_Click` is not the same as the `a` in `button3_Click` (not to mention they are assigned to different arrays).

If you need them to be shared, `a` should be declared at the class level (ie, not in a method). Then both methods can use the same variable (just don't re-assign it!).

Also:

- `a.Clone();` doesn't do anything unless you assign the result
- Calling `Sort` in your loop is totally overkill
- `Random tal = new Random()` isn't even used in `button3_click`

Comment: so i took the sort out of the loop now, but how can i get the numbers from listbox1 to be the same in listbox3 just sorted? cause it's just different numbers it sorts in listbox3

Comment: but when i moved the sort out of the loop i get a number like "19" as lowest even though the number after is "2"?